# How to get webpage body using ruby after passing form data

Tags: ruby, post, rest-client

Basically to get the body of webpage i used to do this.

```
require "rest-client"
url="example.com"
test=RestClient.get(url)
```

But now the webpage has setup an authentication step. On entering the correct password you go to `PAGE A` else you go to `PAGE B`. My question is how do i login using the id and password. You can think of the page as [this one here](http://115.248.50.60/registration/Main.jsp?sessionId=1503318374759&wispId=1)

I enter the credentials using the script and find out if I logged in or not.

**Edit:** Simplifying I want to know how do i pass the user name and password and I want to know the URL of the page that opened after login button is clicked.

Please note that this is not at all a hijack attempt. I just want to know if this can be done or not. The website i gave is just an example.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. It uses a post query. Its just like brute-forcing a google login but with unlimited number of tries and the same result everytime.

Comment: Look at `mechanize` gem. It helps interact with forms. http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in fact, but I would say this solution isn't very correct.

On the link page you've provided you can find `form` tag with an action field `action="/registration/chooseAuth.do;jsessionid=73f8323730d5704b00f173314aaeaad2de767c0c0c42.e34Nb38TbhaTbO0Tc34Sbx0Obhv0n6jAmljGr5XDqQLvpAe"`

This is the link to actual authorization, so you can do something like that:

```
RestClient.post(url_from_the_form, { login: 'foo', password: 'bar' })
```

And it might work, but. What you do is called web scraping or web crawling. There are tools which are more suitable for that:

[Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) (the simplest one)
[Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) + [Selenium WebDriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver)

Mechanize works great for rather simple webpages. When it comes to more AJAX or SPA, you better chose Capybara + Selenium.

Comment: How do i get the url from the form?

Comment: You can open html page content, find the `form` tag and the url you will find in the `action=` field of that tag.

Comment: So is `/registration/checkTime.do` a valid url? It was after the `action=` field under `form` tag.

Comment: with a hostname of course, but yes. And login/password fields you can find inside the form tag in `input` fields, probably id= or name= values are keys for login and password.

Comment: Ya thanks I found out the keys `loginUserId: 'foo', loginPassword: 'bar' `. It worked.